# Use of Meteor-ui-progress-circle (accessing to Template variables created in the HTML)

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

It may be a very dumb question... I am using [Meteor-ui-progress-circle](https://github.com/MeteorWidgets/Meteor-ui-progress-circle/) and I want redrawing the template when the percentage (wich is store in a reactive collection Progress) is changed (currently, when I click on a "play" button).
I think I have to use Blaze.render but I don't really understand how it work.

Here a part of my main template (in Jade) :

```
div.panel-body
    div.col-md-9.col-sm-8 
         p Lorem ipsum...
    div.col-md-3.col-sm-4#progress-circle
        +progressCircle progress="0" radius="100" class="green"
```

And my JavaScript :

```
Template.controlBar.events(
{
  "click .play-button": function ()
  {
    var tmp = Progress.findOne({});
    if (!tmp)
    {
        Meteor.call('createProgress');
        tmp = Progress.findOne({});
    }
    var val = tmp.progressValue;
    val += 10;
    if (val > 100)
        return;
    Meteor.call('updateProgess', tmp._id, val);
    Template.progressCircle.progress = tmp.progressValue;
    Blaze.render(Template.progressCircle, $("#progress-circle")[0]);
},
```

Doing this... I have several template that are displaying each time I click on the play button. I don't understand how to specify that I don't want a new template but just re-render the one I already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I quite understand your question, but I'll try to help by giving my best understanding of templating and how I have come to use them.  If someone sees any incorrect information here, please speak up so I can get a better understanding myself and correct this answer.

First, the `Template.XXX.events` handlers.  In your event handler, you are using a function with no arguments.  You can actually accept 2 arguments for these event handler functions: the `event` and the `template`.  So, you can do something like thus:

```
Template.controlBar.events({
  'click .play_button': function(event, tmpl) {
    tmpl.$('div#progress-circle').doSomething();
  }
});
```

Notice the `tmpl.$()` call?  That says to use jQuery to find the specified selector, but ONLY in the current template.  This is a wonderful way to use classes to generalize your components, but then be able to filter the selection to only those within the same template...

...Which brings me to my next bit of advice: Use child templates excessively.  Any component that I can identify as an "autonomous component" on my page I will consider as a separate template.  For instance, I was recently working on a custom reporting page that had a table and some D3 graphs representing some real-time data.  In this report page, I had one main template defined for the "page", then each of the D3 graphs where defined as a separate template, and the table was another separate template.  This allows several advantages:

1. Compartmentalization of the "components" of the page, allowing code reuse (I can now put the same graph on ANY page, since it's now an autonomous "component"
2. The advantage of using the `Template.XXX.events` trick above to "narrow" the scope of my element searches to elements within that template
3. Prevents total page refreshes as Meteor is smart enough to only refresh templates that need to be refreshed, which also speeds the responsiveness of the page itself

As a result, I try to apply my Templates liberally.  In your case, it would sound to me that if I were to have multiply progress bars on the page that I might turn those into separate templates.  I might even do it if I had a single progress bar if it made sense to separate it out for ease of data handling.

Finally, inter-communications between Templates.  This can be tricky at times, but the best, most efficient way to do this I have found is through `Session` variables.  The pattern I typically use is to have my data for my template be returned by a Template `.helper`, which does something like this:

```
Template.controlBar.helpers({
  progressData: function() {
    if (!Session.equals('playId', null)) {
      return Progress.findOne({_play_id: Session.get('playId')});
    }
  }
});
```

Because Helpers are reactive, and Sessions is reactive, the template is re-rendered anytime the `'playId'` is altered in the Session.  The corresponding Session variable can be set from anywhere in the client code.  Again, this tends to work best when you narrow the scope of your templates to the individual components.  It is important to note here that the Session object in Meteor is NOT the same as "sessions" in other languages like Java and such, which typically use cookies and a session token/id.  Meteor sessions work considerably different, and do not survive page reloads or closing of browsers.

Comment: Thank you for your post, I better understand some concepts now. Each template is an object with property, I don't understand how to access to custom variables of a template like "progress" or "radius" in this case.

Comment: Well, in the example above you can access the `progressData` via the helper in your Template using Spacebars like thus: `{{progressData}}`.  Can can even access parts of it, for instance `{{progressData.currentValue}}` would access the `currentValue` of the returned `progressData` helper.  Think of the helpers like variables that exist in your template.

Comment: Yeah... I've already understood how to access in my HTML code to variables I've create in the JavaScript. But I don't know how to access in my JavaScript the variables I created in the HTML. Tell me if I'm wrong but in this context `+progressCircle progress="0"`, `progress` is a variable created in the HTML.

Comment: If you are referring to passing values to a template, my understanding is that doing that modifies the expected "`this`" of the template, meaning that in your example doing `{{progress}}` in your template would output 0, and accessing `this` inside any helper or doing something like `Blaze.getData(XXX)` in your event handler in the JS for the template and printing that would yield `{ progress : 0 }` as the object.  I have used this method to build recursive select options where I needed to know the depth plus the value I needed to operate on.